# Random variable with finite expectation and unbounded variance

Tags: probability, random-variables

What is an example of a random variable with finite expectation and unbounded variance?

I'm thinking about putting $1/n$ probability on each of $n$ equally-spaced points. Then as $n$ approaches infinity, more stuff is far from the mean. But for any particular $n$ the variance will be bounded. Can we modify this somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^3}=\zeta(3)$

This means $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\zeta(3)k^3}=1$ would be a great probability distribution.

Let $P(X=k)=\frac{1}{\zeta(3)k^3}$ on $k=1,2,\dots$

Now $E[X]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kP(X=k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\zeta(3)k^2}=\frac{\zeta(2)}{\zeta(3)}<\infty$

But $E[X^2]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2P(X=k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\zeta(3)k}$ diverges

And thus, the variance of $X$ is infinite

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try density $f(x) = C/x^p$ for $x \ge 1$ for suitable $C$ and $p$ (or if you prefer a discrete case, $P(X = n) = C/n^p$).